# What do these phrases in the game of cricket mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language, idiom-request

I like watching cricket. I hear phrases like:

> He played a great innings and **brought his team home**.
>
> He remained there till the end to ensure he **sees his team home**.

And:

> He is in the **form of his life.**

What do the phrases in the bold mean? 
In the initial ones, I could not understand in what context they are using the word **"home"**. I am sure it means winning the match though.

Comment: None of these phrases are specifc to cricket. The only term that is unique to cricket in the OP's sentences is "innings," which is a singular noun in cricket, but a plural noun in baseball. (The plural form of the cricket term is also also "innings").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, the first two phrases mean the team is winning. It's used here in the sense of

> 2 b: to or at an ultimate objective (such as a goal or finish line)
>   // fired the puck *home*

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home))</sub>

The *form of his life* means that the player is in his best form ever, see the following definition of 'of one's life':

> Being the greatest, worst, or best occasion of a lifetime

<sub>(source: [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/of+his+life))</sub>

Comment: "Form" would be used similarly to "shape", yes? On top of one's game?

Comment: Yes, correct. [Definition 12c](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/form).